# Receiving multiple HTTP requests from Firefox 12.0 on an App Engine handler

Tags: python, google-app-engine, firefox, webapp2

I'm experiencing some bizarre behavior with Firefox 12.0 and a Python handler on GAE.

When I request this handler in Firefox, it runs 3 times -- but ONLY when it's returning a GIF.

I'm currently hacking around it by setting a memcache entry based on the handler's querystring. I'm hoping this will prevent duplicate db.put()s of the same info.

Here's a working URL: http://test-o-tron.appspot.com -- note you can change these querystring parameters:

- format ("gif" or "html")
- hack ("true" or "false")
- mkey_suffix (string used in memcache keys for easily resetting the counter)

Here's the code:

```
from google.appengine.api import urlfetch, memcache
from google.appengine.ext import db
import webapp2, random

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        #If user doesn't have an mkey_suffix, make one
        if self.request.get("mkey_suffix") == "":
            self.redirect("/?format=gif&hack=false&mkey_suffix=" + 
                          self.request.remote_addr + 
                          "." + str(random.randint(0, 1000)))


        OUTPUT_GIF = self.request.get("format") == "gif"
        USE_HACK = self.request.get("hack") == "true"

        #Memcache keys
        mkey_suffix = self.request.get("mkey_suffix")
        mkey_log = "log" + mkey_suffix
        mkey_hack = "hack" + mkey_suffix

        #Count the number of requests using memcache
        if memcache.get(mkey_log) is None:
            memcache.set(mkey_log, 0, 60)
        counter = memcache.get(mkey_log)

        #Hack!! Only handle a given request ONCE every second
        if not USE_HACK or memcache.get(mkey_hack) is None:
            memcache.set(mkey_hack, True, time=1)

            #Show I'm not crazy
            counter += 1
            memcache.set(mkey_log, counter, 60)

        #Return counter value 
        if OUTPUT_GIF:

            self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "image/gif"
            img_url = "http://placehold.it/{counter}x{counter}"
            img_url = img_url.format(counter=str(400 + counter))
            img_data = urlfetch.Fetch(img_url).content
            content = db.Blob(img_data)


        else:

            #Output HTML 
            self.response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html"
            content = "Counter == " + str(counter)

        self.response.out.write(content)


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The AppEngine team has reported the following error:

> **Investigating reports of a Google App Engine issue in which requests are being executed multiple times on June 13, 2013**
>
> We are investigating reports of an issue with Google App Engine in
>   which a request can get executed multiple times. This shows up in
>   Admin Console logs as a request to a frontend that runs for longer
>   than a minute. We will provide more information shortly.

On June 14, they issued the following update:

> We have determined the root cause, and implemented a fix, which will
>   be rolling out over the next few days.  You should expect little to no
>   ongoing impact to running applications.  We will provide a more
>   detailed analysis of this issue once we have completed our internal
>   investigation.

Comment: "The problem with Google App Engine requests that get executed multiple times was resolved as of 10:38 PM US/Pacific on June 17 2013. We apologize for the inconvenience and thank you for your patience and continued support. Please rest assured that system reliability is a top priority at Google, and we are making continuous improvements to make our systems better. We will provide a more detailed analysis of this incident once we have completed our internal investigation."

Answer (score 1):

You can get equivalent info out of your request logs without resorting that that kind of hack.

Are you intending to have your app service dynamic GIFs? If your GIFs are static, and you declare them as such in `app.yaml`, the handler is bypassed completely. There may be still be some sort of firefox hiccup, but the load on your app won't reflect it.

See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/staticfiles

Comment: This is a tracking pixel so I need to parse the querystring that's attached to it.

Answer (score 0):

What's your question? I betcha this is some kind of Firefox behavior where it is requesting a favicon or trying to look ahead or something.

Comment: Ah -- I thought it would be obvious, but the question is: "How can I work around this issue without resorting to a hack?"

Comment: You had better understand why FF seNds three requests first.